# Cocoa - NSDictionary from zipped plist?

Tags: cocoa, zip, plist, nsdata

Mac OS X 10.5 compatibility required.

I have a (large, complex) NSDictionary I'm writing out as a plist file.

For file size reasons, I want to zip the file, and later read it in again from the zip archive.

(I can also save it as as a binary plist, to save some space. But not enough for my purposes.)

The zipping/unzipping part is easy, thanks to the NSData category provided at:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory

This gives me an NSData object from the zip archive.

**Q.** Is there a safe/auto-magic/approved way of taking that unzipped NSData object and combobulating it in to a valid NSDictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the NSPropertyListSerialization Class Reference.

Comment: I am using NSPropertyListSerialization to save the file out as a binary plist, but that does not afford me the file size savings that zipping does. Or do you mean some other approach?

Comment: Use the appropriate method on `NSPropertyListSerialization` to deserialize the data as a plist, which you know to be a dictionary. I believe it begins with `+propertyListFromData:` or something like that.

Comment: I mean using NSPropertyListSerialization to go from an NSData to an NSDictionary.  That's under the heading "Deserializing a Property List".

Comment: Thank you both JW and JW. ;)  Yes, that did the trick. I'm now serialising the NSDictionary to an NSData object then zipping that object, before saving it.  I'm reversing the process to get it back to an NSDictionary.  Cheers.